# Prove that the real interval (0,10) is equipotent to its subset (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have a question regarding the following solution to the problem:

"Every infinite decimal is of the form $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ (where $a_i \in \{0,1,2,...9\}$ and the digits are not all $0$ and not all $9$) corresponds bijectively to the infinite decimal $a_1.a_2a_3...$ this shows that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the elements of (0,1) and (0,10)"

My question:

For an element in $(0,1)$ say $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ are there not two corresponding elements in $(0,10)$ namely  $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ and $a_1.a_2a_3...$  ?

Why in the solution does $0.a_1a_2a_3...$ correspond only to $a_1.a_2a_3... $?

Comment: Multiplication by $10$ is invertible (by multiplication by $1/10$).

Comment: They are **defining** the relationship as $\phi(0.a_1 a_2...) = a_1.a_2...$. So, $0.1$ will correspond to $1.0$ , $0.01$ will correspond to $0.1$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the solution is defining a specific bijection $f:(0,1)\to(0,10)$ by the rule $f(0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots)=a_1.a_2a_3\ldots$. In other words, for a given $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots\in(0,1)$, there is one and only one $f(0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots)\in(0,10)$, which is *defined* to be $a_1.a_2a_3\ldots$.

It is also true that for $a_1.a_2a_3\ldots\in(0,10)$, there is one and only one $f^{-1}(a_1.a_2a_3\ldots)\in(0,1)$, which is simply $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$.